# Why is there such a large performance difference between these two scrips that do the same thing?

Tags: raku

This is problem36 from the Euler Project. Sum all of the numbers below a million that are palindromic in base 2 and base 10.

I'd originally tried solving it in a more functional style.

This runs in just under 6 seconds.

```
[1..1_000_000]
    .grep( * !%% 2 )
    .grep( -> $x { $x == $x.flip } )
    .grep( -> $y { $y.base(2) == $y.base(2).flip } )
    .sum.say
```

Surprisingly this took 12 seconds even though I'm only generating odd numbers and therefore
skipping the test for even.

```
(1,3 ... 1_000_000)
    .grep( -> $x { $x == $x.flip } )
    .grep( -> $y { $y.base(2) == $y.base(2).flip } )
    .sum.say
```

This runs in about 3 seconds.

```
my @pals;
for (1,3 ... 1_000_000) -> $x {
    next unless $x == $x.flip;
    next unless $x.base(2) == $x.base(2).flip;
    @pals.push($x);
}

say [+] @pals;
```

I also noted that there is a significant difference between using

```
for (1,3 ... 1_000_000) -> $x { ...
```

and

```
for [1,3 ... 1_000_000] -> $x { ...
```

Anyone know why the streaming versions are so much slower than the iterative one?
And, why would those two for loops be so different in performance?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The construct `[...]` is an array composer. It eagerly iterates the iterable found within it, and stores each value into the array. Only then do we proceed to do the iteration. That results in far more memory allocation and is less cache-friendly. By contrast, parentheses do nothing (aside from grouping, but they don't add any semantics beyond that). Thus:

```
[1..1_000_000]
    .grep( * !%% 2 )
    .grep( -> $x { $x == $x.flip } )
    .grep( -> $y { $y.base(2) == $y.base(2).flip } )
    .sum.say
```

Will allocate and set up a million element array and iterate it, while:

```
(1..1_000_000)
    .grep( * !%% 2 )
    .grep( -> $x { $x == $x.flip } )
    .grep( -> $y { $y.base(2) == $y.base(2).flip } )
    .sum.say
```

Runs rather faster, because it need not do that.

Further, the `...` operator is currently far slower than the `..` operator. It's not doomed to be that way forever, it's just received a lot less attention so far. Since `.grep` has also been decently well optimized, it turns out to be quicker to filter out the elements made by the range - for now, anyway.

Finally, using `==` to compare the (string) results of `base` and `flip` is not so efficient, since it parses them back into integers, when we could use `eq` and compare the strings:

```
(1 .. 1_000_000)
    .grep(* !%% 2)
    .grep( -> $x { $x eq $x.flip } )
    .grep( -> $y { $y.base(2) eq $y.base(2).flip } )
    .sum.say
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The fastest result for me was the iterative one, in my post, after I replaced the '==' with 'eq' - it sped it up considerably.  I noticed that I'm using version 2019.03 so I'll need to update it and see what kind of difference that makes when using grep.

Answer (score 5):

If you want something that is faster, you can write your own sequence generator.

```raku
gather {
  loop (my int $i = 1; $i < 1_000_000; $i += 2) {
    take $i
  }
}
.grep( -> $x { $x eq $x.flip } )
.grep( -> $y { $y.base(2) eq $y.base(2).flip } )
.sum.say
```

Which takes about 4 seconds.

---

Or to go even faster, you can create the Iterator object yourself.

```raku
class Odd does Iterator {
    has uint $!count = 1;

    method pull-one () {
        if ($!count += 2) < 1_000_000 {
            $!count
        } else {
            IterationEnd
        }
    }
}

Seq.new(Odd.new)
.grep( -> $x { $x == $x.flip } )
.grep( -> $y { $y.base(2) == $y.base(2).flip } )
.sum.say
```

Which only takes about 2 seconds.

---

Of course if you want to go as fast as possible, get rid of the sequence iteration entirely.

Also use native `int`s.

Also cache the base 10 string. `(my $s = ~$x)`

```raku
my int $acc = 0;
loop ( my int $x = 1; $x < 1_000_000; $x += 2) {
  next unless (my $s = ~$x) eq $s.flip;
  next unless $x.base(2) eq $x.base(2).flip;
  $acc += $x
}
say $acc;
```

Which gets it down to about `0.45` seconds.

(Caching the `.base(2)` didn't seem to do anything.)

This is probably close to the minimum without resorting to using `nqp` ops directly.

---

I tried writing a native int bit flipper, but it made it slower. `0.5` seconds.
(I did not come up with this algorithm, I only adapted it to Raku. I also added the `+> $in.msb` to fit this problem.)

I would guess that *spesh* is leaving in operations that don't need to be there.
Or maybe it isn't **JIT**ting very well.

It might be more performant for values larger than `1_000_000`.
(`.base(2).flip` is `O(log n)` whereas this is `O(1)`.)

```raku
sub flip-bits ( int $in --> int ) {
  my int $n =
       ((($in +& (my int $ = 0xaaaaaaaa)) +> 1) +| (($in +& (my int $ = 0x55555555)) +< 1));
  $n = ((($n  +& (my int $ = 0xcccccccc)) +> 2) +| (($n  +& (my int $ = 0x33333333)) +< 2));
  $n = ((($n  +& (my int $ = 0xf0f0f0f0)) +> 4) +| (($n  +& (my int $ = 0x0f0f0f0f)) +< 4));
  $n = ((($n  +& (my int $ = 0xff00ff00)) +> 8) +| (($n  +& (my int $ = 0x00ff00ff)) +< 8));
  ((($n +> 16) +| ($n+< 16)) +> (32 - 1 - $in.msb)) +& (my int $ = 0xffffffff);
}

…

  # next unless (my $s = ~$x) eq $s.flip;
  next unless $x == flip-bits($x);
```

---

You can even try to use multiple threads.

Note that this workload is entirely too little for this to be effective.
The overhead of using threads swamps out any benefit.

```raku
my atomicint $total = 0;

sub process ( int $s, int $e ) {
  # these are so the block lambda works properly
  # (works around what I think is a bug)
  my int $ = $s;
  my int $ = $e;

  start {
    my int $acc = 0;
    loop ( my int $x = $s; $x < $e; $x += 2) {
      next unless (my $s = ~$x) eq $s.flip;
      next unless $x.base(2) eq $x.base(2).flip;
      $acc += $x;
    }
    $total ⚛+= $acc;
  }
}


my int $cores = (Kernel.cpu-cores * 2.2).Int;

my int $per = 1_000_000 div $cores;
++$per if $per * $cores < 1_000_000;

my @promises;

my int $start = 1;
for ^$cores {
  my int $end = $start + $per - 2;
  $end = 1_000_000 if $end > 1_000_000;

  push @promises, process $start, $end;

#say $start, "\t", $end;

  $start = $end + 2;
}

await @promises;
say $total;
```

Which runs in about `0.63` seconds.
(I messed with the `2.2` value to find a near minimum time on my computer.)

Comment: my @pals;
for (1,3 ... 1_000_000) -> $x {
    next unless $x eq $x.flip; 
    next unless $x.base(2) eq $x.base(2).flip;
    @pals.push($x);
}  say [+] @pals;
Taking the iterative version of my post and replacing '==' with 'eq' ran in .5 seconds.